# What is $D_i^h$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation, partial-derivative

I'm looking at [solution seven in here.](http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~d04221001/Notes/Problems%20and%20Solutions%20Section/Evans%20PDE/Evans%20PDE%20Solution%20Chapter%206%20Second-Order%20Elliptic%20Equations.pdf)

They write $v=-D_i^{-h}D_i^h u$ $0<|h|<<1$

What is $D_i^h$? They use $\nabla$ for the gradient, so I don't think it is the $i^{th}$ component of the gradient. I don't think it is $\partial_i$, as in taking $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ since then I wouldn't know what taking $\partial_i^h$ would possibly mean, since $0<h<1$.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a discrete difference approximation to the $i^{\text{th}}$ partial derivative of $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a discrete difference approximation to the $i^{\text{th}}$ partial derivative of $u$.

See $5.8$ of Evans.